# Apache server - firefox xls.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read

Tags: php, excel, apache

I am using Apache server and trying to download xls or xlsx file but always getting below error in firefox 48 version.

- FILENAME.xls.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.
- FILENAME.xlsx.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

Download is giving download fail error on IE 11 for first time but later it is working fine.

Also, on chrome download is working fine.

What might be the issue?

Below are the response headers

```
Cache-Control:"private"
Connection:"Keep-Alive"
Content-Description:"PHP Generated Data"
Content-Disposition:"attachment; filename=SampleExcel.xlsx"
Content-Length:"9336"
Content-Type:"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
Date:"Thu, 25 Aug 2016 00:52:45 GMT"
Expires:"Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
Keep-Alive:"timeout=5, max=100"
Pragma:"no-cache"
Server:"Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12"
Set-Cookie:"loginid=1"
X-Powered-By:"PHP/5.5.12"
```

Comment: Do you control the server / application that's providing the download?

Comment: Yes. I can access application.

Comment: That's not my question. Are you trying to fix something that you built / control / need to fix, or just trying to use a web browser? Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions; the first situation is arguably, just barely, on topic. The second is not.

Comment: I have implemented functionality to download excel file. It was working fine but from last month getting error for excel file download in firefox and IE. I want to fix download issue by changing setting in apache server or through php programming.

Comment: Put some code or errors on you question...

Comment: Error - FILENAME.xlsx.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.

Comment: I have added actual response headers. Can anyone help?

Comment: Facing same problem.